# Convert JSON bidimensional array to an AS3 array

Tags: arrays, json, actionscript-3, actionscript

Im trying convert a JSON result (bidimensional array) to an bidimensional array in Action Script 3 but something is wrong. Can someone help me ?

My JSON result is:
`{"area:": [[3, 3, 7], [18, 15, 2], [12, 8, 5], [13, 1, 3], [2, 15, 4], [7, 12, 3]]}`

My As3 code is:

```
function completeHandlerGetAreas(e:Event):void
{
    try
    {
        var result:Object = JSON.decode(e.target.data);
        var array:Array = result.area;
        trace(array[0][0]);

    }
    catch (e:Error)
    {
        trace('ERROR - Nao foi possivel decodificar o getAreas!');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var received_data = '{"area" : [[3, 3, 7], [18, 15, 2], [12, 8, 5], [13, 1, 3], [2, 15, 4], [7, 12, 3]]}'
//                     ¨¨¨¨ note here that is "area" and not "area:"

try {
    var result:Object = JSON.parse(received_data);
    var array:Array = result.area
    trace(array[4][1]) // it must give : 15
}
catch (e:Error) {
    trace('error : '+e.toString())
}
```